# Python Regex with String for Space

Tags: python, regex

I have a program that needs to find the name of a network using regex. The network will be in the form of: "ASCII ASCII" followed by a `\r` or `\n`.

I need to include the space, but can't have any of the `\r` or `\n` in there. My problem is that I have to use `re`, and using `re.search` won't work with `\r` or `\n`.

I have

```
re.search("(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*\s)", networks)
```

Which gives me everything until the space, and

```
re.search("(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)
```

which gives me everything in the list.

Every time I try to do

```
re.search("(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)(\r|\n)", networks)
```

or something similar, the string returned is NULL.

How can I do this?

EDIT:

networks is:

```
b'\r\nProfiles on interface Wi-Fi:\r\n\r\nGroup policy profiles (read only)\r\n---------------------------------\r\n    <None>\r\n\r\nUser profiles\r\n-------------\r\n    All User Profile     : NAME 2.4\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: Use `$` along with the `re.MULTILINE` flag to match a newline.

Comment: Please post the `networks` variable declaration.

Comment: Compiling with re.MULTILINE does not work. I put (.*$) instead of (.*), but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

You need a non-greedy match, or the capture gets the `\r` also when you use the `(\r|\n)`:

```
import re

networks = b'\r\nProfiles on interface Wi-Fi:\r\n\r\nGroup policy profiles (read only)\r\n---------------------------------\r\n    <None>\r\n\r\nUser profiles\r\n-------------\r\n    All User Profile     : NAME 2.4\r\n\r\n'
m = re.search(rb'Profile\s+:\s+(.*?)(?:\r|\n)',networks)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
b'NAME 2.4'
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much.